# Return a column range in which a string is in a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is an example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P91qqhClA8oO3-N9OGSxrFH-6lXxttZ3IN4bIGRGjHw/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to get the column range returned in when the string in INPUT!B1 can be seen in DATABASE!A2:A into INPUT!C1:C3

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(DATABASE!A:C,DATABASE!A:A=B1)
```

`VLookup()`, `Index/Match()`, `QUERY()` all these functions will work for you.

[image]